# How to awake the app when user shake the mobile phone in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, background-fetch

I am using [CallKeep](https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep) to awake the app (for shake detection I am using [Shake plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/shake)) when shaking the mobile, I want to up the flutter app when user shake the phone and app is killed.

I know I can use [background_fetch: ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/background_fetch), but problem is that it only allows after every 15 minutes, I want to listen shake event all the time.

Please help me out I am stuck here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check the code snippet and API documentation carefully. There is a property inside of configure called minimumFetchInterval. You can adjust the value and check if it works, should work.

[api-doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/background_fetch/latest/background_fetch/BackgroundFetch-class.html) Following code snippet is placed under Android part in api doc.

```
BackgroundFetch.configure(BackgroundFetchConfig(
  minimumFetchInterval: 15,  // <-- minutes
  stopOnTerminate: false,
  startOnBoot: true
), (String taskId) async {  // <-- Event callback
  // This callback is typically fired every 15 minutes while in the background.
  print('[BackgroundFetch] Event received.');
  // IMPORTANT:  You must signal completion of your fetch task or the OS could
  // punish your app for spending much time in the background.
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
}, (String taskId) async {  // <-- Task timeout callback
  // This task has exceeded its allowed running-time.  You must stop what you're doing and immediately .finish(taskId)
  BackgroundFetch.finish(taskId);
})
```